# useCallback onChange always shows previous values

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have 30 inputs

and i want to auto/manual fire httprequests on text change

but somehow `useCallback` prints previous values

I want to use `useCallback` as I want to keep same function reference when it is deeply passed to component,and avoids re-renders

[image: Edit dank-sun-h68kk]

```js
    import React, { useState, useCallback } from "react";
    
    export default function App() {
      const [name, setName] = useState("tom");
      const verifyName = useCallback(() => {
        console.log(`HttpRequest for name ${name}`);
      }, [name]);
     
      return (
        <div>
          Name <input value={name} onChange={(e) => {
              setName(e.target.value);
              verifyName();
            }}
          /> 
          <button onClick={verifyName}> check name </button>

        </div>
      );
    }
```

[image: Edit dank-sun-h68kk]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your event listener.

```
onChange={(e) => {
    setName(e.target.value);
    verifyName();
}}
```

By the time you call `verifyName` (which is a side effect), you scheduled a new name with `setName`, but this operation is asynchronous. As the docs say:

> The setState function is used to update the state. It accepts a new
> state value and enqueues a re-render of the component.

Class components accept a second argument for `setState`, an update callback that only executes after the state is new. Functional components, however, don't accept that anymore. The React way to do this is to use the `useEffect` hook:

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(`Http request for name ${name}`);
}, [name]);
```

**EDIT**: [Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-edison-1yw1h)

Comment: if i move `http` request to `useEffect` then i will loose `useCallback`

Comment: You can mix useCallback. BTW, pass an array dependency to useCallback too, otherwise it will recompute everytime.

Comment: Nice try, but this design adds new usecase,Http req fires on page load,And in question it does not fire on page load

Comment: You can always create a custom hook to ignore the effect on mount https://stackoverflow.com/q/55075604/6281832

Answer (score 0):

[image: Edit ecstatic-tharp-6joi6]

**Changed**

```jsx
  <input
    value={name}
    onChange={(e) => {
      setName(e.target.value);
      verifyName();
    }}
  />
```

**To**

```jsx
  <input
    value={name}
    onChange={(e) => {
      setName(e.target.value);
      verifyName(e.target.value);
    }}
  />
```

And

**Changed**

```js
  const verifyName = useCallback(() => {
    console.log(`Http request for name ${name}`);
  }, [name]);
```

**To**

```js
  const verifyName = useCallback((nameToChange) => {
    console.log(`Http request for name ${nameToChange}`);
  }, []);
```

Explanation

1. `setName` which is asynchronus dosen't have second param like `setState`
2. if i use `useEffect` then i loose `useCallback`
3. now only option left was to pass `new value` to dead `useCallback` verifyName func