# Use useEffect in react functional class to write data to firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, use-effect

The code persistently Data stores in Firebase which is what I wanted after each session, but it's hacky because  `setOnes([...ones,1])` and `writeToFirebase` shouldn't be called under the same functions due to async, but every time I tried with `useEffect(()=>writeToFirebase(),[setOnes])` to achieve similar result as `ComponentDidUpdate`, it got triggered right at the beginning of the launch and reset to FB database back to [1,1]. This is the code I have, codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/super-simple-react-firebase-functional-class-hook-set-up-eyo15?file=/src/App2.js:279-326

```
const App2 = () =>{
  
  const [ones, setOnes] = useState([1,1]);
  useEffect(() => {
    Firebase.initializeApp(config)
    getFromFirebase()
  }, []);

  // useEffect(()=>writeToFirebase(),[setOnes])

  const writeToFirebase = () => {
    Firebase.database()
      .ref("/")
      .set(ones);
    console.log("DATA SAVED");
  };

  const getFromFirebase = () => {
    let ref = Firebase.database().ref("/");
    ref.on("value", snapshot => {
      const state = snapshot.val();
      setOnes(state)
    })
  }

  const handleAdd =() => {
    setOnes([...ones,1])
    writeToFirebase()
  }
    
    const list = ones.map((e,i)=>( 
        <div
            key={e.id}
        > {e} </div>
    ))
  
    return ( 
    <div>
      {list}
      <button onClick={handleAdd}>Add</button>
    </div> 
    )
}

export default App2;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use `setones` as a dependency in useEffect, use `ones`.
Full Code will look like this

```
const App2 = () =>{
  
  const [ones, setOnes] = useState([1,1]);
  useEffect(() => {
    Firebase.initializeApp(config)
    getFromFirebase()
  }, []);

  useEffect(()=>writeToFirebase(),[ones])

  const writeToFirebase = () => {
    Firebase.database()
      .ref("/")
      .set(ones);
    console.log("DATA SAVED");
  };

  const getFromFirebase = () => {
    let ref = Firebase.database().ref("/");
    ref.on("value", snapshot => {
      const state = snapshot.val();
      setOnes(state)
    })
  }

  const handleAdd =() => {
    setOnes([...ones,1])
  }
    
    const list = ones.map((e,i)=>( 
        <div
            key={e.id}
        > {e} </div>
    ))
  
    return ( 
    <div>
      {list}
      <button onClick={handleAdd}>Add</button>
    </div> 
    )
}

export default App2;
```

Altenatively, if you want to call `writeToFirebase()` only when `ones` change and not on initial render, you can use a custom hook `useDidUpdateEffect`. You can find the code in the answer to this question [React hooks useEffect only on update?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55075604/react-hooks-useeffect-only-on-update). In that case the full code will look like this

```
const App2 = () =>{
  
  const [ones, setOnes] = useState([1,1]);
  const isInitialMount = useRef(true);
  useEffect(() => {
    Firebase.initializeApp(config)
    getFromFirebase()
  }, []);

  
  useEffect(() => {
  if (isInitialMount.current) {
       isInitialMount.current = false;
     } else {
     writeToFirebase();
    }
  }, [ones]);

  const writeToFirebase = () => {
    Firebase.database()
      .ref("/")
      .set(ones);
    console.log("DATA SAVED");
  };

  const getFromFirebase = () => {
    let ref = Firebase.database().ref("/");
    ref.on("value", snapshot => {
      const state = snapshot.val();
      setOnes(state)
    })
  }

  const handleAdd =() => {
    setOnes([...ones,1])
  }
    
    const list = ones.map((e,i)=>( 
        <div
            key={e.id}
        > {e} </div>
    ))
  
    return ( 
    <div>
      {list}
      <button onClick={handleAdd}>Add</button>
    </div> 
    )
}

export default App2
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, thanks for the answer and link to the other page, i used `useRef`to run write on update only!

Comment: Welcome @carterx, please mark the answer as accepted for other users.

Answer (score 0):

You should write useEffect(()=>writeToFirebase(),[ones]) instead of
// useEffect(()=>writeToFirebase(),[setOnes])

useEffect(()=>writeToFirebase(),[ones]) means that writeToFirebase will execute each time ones change. ones is the state variable here, setOnes is a function.

Comment: Sorry I have tried that, but it doesn't seem to work, I think when `setOnes`, it also changes the state of `Ones`, so useEffect still runs `writeToFirebase()` at the beginning of the launch...

Comment: Thanks for your answer,  this is the fix to my code

const isInitialMount = useRef(true);

useEffect(() => {
    if (isInitialMount.current) {
       isInitialMount.current = false;
    } else {
      writeToFirebase()
    }
  },[ones]);