# How to control if componentDidMount inside useEffect with another dependecies?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am using useEffect with two dependicies

```
useEffect(() => {
   if(this is not the first time useEffect is called which means calls after componentDidMount){
     //my operations
   }
}, [props.inputs, props.inputLabels]);
```

Is there a way to control this??

Comment: I can always use a variable state to control if this is the first time it entered but is there a better solution?

Comment: What is the actual question? You want what to happen? Run only once like in componentDidMount but with two deps? Thats the question?

Comment: Are you trying to make your code run only when you have an update in your dependencies? [React hooks useEffect only on update?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55075604)

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#can-i-run-an-effect-only-on-updates

Comment: Yes i am trying to run my code after update at my dependencies but not when the component first mount.

Comment: Nick's answer is usable i think thanks for the answers.