# Get or save axios.get response to setState realtime when button clicked

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks

I'm working on edit/update function and what I want to do is to save the response of axios.get to `setState` right after I click the a specific row from the table.

```
const [dataSystem, setdataSystem] = useState([])
const [systemDetails, setsystemDetails] = ({
   ID: '',
   .....,
})

const getAllSystems = async() => {
  ......
}

const getDependentSystems = async() => { //this is being triggered by a handleselectedSysDep when a row selected
   const response = await axios.get('/API' + ID) //ID is being passed by handleselectedSysDep  from the selected row
   console.log('LIST OF SYSTEM', response.data)
   setdataSystem(response.data)
}

const [selectedSystemID, setselectedSysID] = useState('');
let selectedSysID;
const handleselectedSysDep = (ID, action) => { //will be triggered when a row selected
   setsystemDetails(ID);
   selectedSysID = {...selectedSystemID, 'ID': ID.ID}
   getDependentSystems();
}

useEffect(() => {
   getAllSystems ();
})
```

What I want is when `getDependentSystems()` was called, `setdataSystem` will be populated right away to display the response data of the API since I'm doing edit. Hope you can help me with this.

Here's the result of `console.log('LIST OF SYSTEM', response.data)`

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Does your code not work? What is the problem you're having? Where is `ID` defined and how / when does it get assigned a value?

Comment: I updated my codes @Phil, my problem is I can't `setState` realtime the datas I get from API. I need to display it when button click because I'm doing EDIT/UPDATE function. Thank you

Comment: If I understand you correctly, You want to call `getDependentSystems` when the UPDATE button is clicked?

Comment: No @Micah, kindly check my provided code and it's comments

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a good use-case to use the `useEffect` hook to watch for changes in `systemDetails` and execute your `getDependentSystems()` side-effect.

For example

```js
const [dataSystem, setDataSystem] = useState([])
const [systemDetails, setSystemDetails] = ({
  ID: '',
  //.....,
})

const handleselectedSysDep = (ID, action) => {
  setSystemDetails(ID); // assuming `ID` is an object
}

// Now add an effect to watch for `systemDetails` changes
useEffect(() => {
  if (systemDetails.ID) {
    axios.get(`/API/${systemDetails.ID}`).then(({ data }) => setDataSystem(data))
  }
}, [ systemDetails ]) //  note the dependencies array
```

You can also use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55075818/283366) to only fire the `useEffect` hook after the initial render.

---

FYI, if you only want `getAllSystems()` to execute once when your component is mounted, you should use

```js
useEffect(() => {
  getAllSystems()
}, []) //  note the empty array
```

Comment: Tried this @Phil, however upon loading of the table the `useEffect` ran and I have an error  upon connecting to API since I don't have yet value for `ID`. What I want is to trigger `axios.get` upon selecting a row on my initial load of table(`getAllSystem`). That's the time when the `getDependentSystems` will be triggered

Comment: @JayDee ah, in that case you can add a condition around the Axios call or use something from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55075818/283366)

Comment: Sir @Phil, it doesn't solve my issue. Are you having hard time or confused on my issue Sir? Let me know if what's confused you. Thank you in advance