# useUpdateEffect is not working in React18

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-18

I need to call an effect callback whenever a particular state is changed inside my component but the callback should not be called during the mounting stage. I have created a custom hook ([Refer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55075818/8601185)).

```js
function useUpdateOnlyEffect(callback){

  const componentJustMounted = useRef(true);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!componentJustMounted.current) {
      callback();
    }
    componentJustMounted.current = false;
  }, [callback]);
  

}
```

I've created an example in codesandbox and the code works fine in [React 17](https://codesandbox.io/s/react17-hvs2nv) but it is not working in [React 18](https://codesandbox.io/s/react18-0ljseu) i.e the effect callback is called during mounting as well.
I've checked the changelog of react 18 but couldn't find the solution. Is this happening due to [Automatic Batching](https://reactjs.org/blog/2022/03/29/react-v18.html#whats-new-in-react-18) introduced in React 18?

**Edit:**

This code will work fine in production mode or by removing strict mode. The reason is React team is planning to remove/add sections of UI while preserving the state of the component before unmounting in the future.

> With Strict Mode starting in React 18, whenever a component mounts in
> development, React will simulate immediately unmounting and remounting
> the component:

This is just to ensure our component is resilient to reusability in future.

To know more, refer [Reusable state](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#ensuring-reusable-state) and follow the github discussions [here](https://github.com/reactwg/react-18/discussions/18).

Anyway, if you add additional effect(not sure if it is recommended) to reset the flag(ref) value the hook will work perfectly fine in dev build as well.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      componentJustMounted.current = true;
    };
  }, []);
```

Comment: I've seen your react 18 version is using StrictMode, maybe that's the problem here?

Comment: @coglialoro yes https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#ensuring-reusable-state

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is related to the Strict Mode. See the update here: https://reactjs.org/blog/2022/03/29/react-v18.html#new-strict-mode-behaviors

> To help surface these issues, React 18 introduces a new development-only check to Strict Mode. This new check will automatically unmount and remount every component, whenever a component mounts for the first time, restoring the previous state on the second mount.

So your component is mounted twice in dev mode, on second load, your flag is false.

Comment: I got it now after reading this discussion https://github.com/reactwg/react-18/discussions/18. I believe we need to add another effect to reset the ref that should work.

Answer (score 0):

Is your implementation using rooks, and what version. useUpdateEffect is deprecated in rooks v7 it has been removed.

https://react-hooks.org/docs/useUpdateEffect

Comment: No I'm not using rooks. I've created my own custom hook by referring https://stackoverflow.com/a/55075818/8601185. Btw I've checked useDidUpdate(the alternate to useUpdateEffect) from rooks it also uses the same logic internally.