# How to prevent react useEffect running at component mount when using second parameter

Tags: reactjs

When I run this component, both effects are being called. How to prevent the second one from being called on component mount?

```
const Item = ({route, navigation, ...props}) => {
    const [page, setPage] = useState(0)

    useEffect(() => {
      console.log('component mount')
      //call API with page 0
      //call another API
    }, [])

    useEffect(() => {
      console.log('called', page)
      //call API with page {page}
    }, [page])

    
    console.log('render')
    return (
        <Text>test</Text>
    );
}
```

Comment: yes it should run only if "page" is changed, but on initial rendering it will be fired as well, cause basically it is changed - from "nothing" to 0 in your case

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Hooks - useEffect fires even though the state did not change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54923896/react-hooks-useeffect-fires-even-though-the-state-did-not-change)

Comment: @NikitaChayka I understand it but how to make it not run at the first time because I can't even make if conditions there

Comment: @JBallin it explains why it happens but it doesn't give any workaround to that

Comment: You can use the condition for that in 2nd useEffect

Comment: What do you mean under "i can't even make if"? Your only option would be to have some "if" condition inside second hook. You can check ideas here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53253940/make-react-useeffect-hook-not-run-on-initial-render

Comment: I can't use any condition there. If I check to make the API call when page is not 0 then what when user goes from page 1 to page 0?

Comment: @NikitaChayka I can make an if condition there but like I explained in my previous comment that doesn't work in my case for pagination

Comment: @EdisonBiba check this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53253940/make-react-useeffect-hook-not-run-on-initial-render
The best answer there is to useRef to handle this

Comment: Please refer this for workaround https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53253940/make-react-useeffect-hook-not-run-on-initial-render

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`useEffect` will always run on the initial render, but you can use conditions to determine what actions should be taken within the effect.

In your case no conditions are needed, you just need to remove API call for page 0 in your first effect - so that it gets called in your 2nd.

Comment: Yes that's what I did. Thank you